# Function to convert cell range to text without VBA

Tags: excel, text, switch-statement, range

I'm trying to use SWITCH function in EXCEL with a cell range but would like to output it as in a single cell rather than an array as seen in the picture.

My formula is as below. I'm "forced" to use strings as an alternative but this not really practical.

=SWITCH($D$2;"A";"A32:A56";"B";"K32:K56";"C";"T32:T52";"D";"AC32:AI56")

[image]

I would like to output the range into a single cell rather than an array.

Does anyone has an idea how to go about this?

Best,
R

Answer (score 0):

Use the [textjoin function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) to join your array output into a single cell.

```
=textjoin(",";false;SWITCH($D$2;"A";"A32:A56";"B";"K32:K56";"C";"T32:T52";"D";"AC32:AI56"))
```

Note, the formating for yours may differ as the quotes around your range seemed problematic.

Simpler formula:

`=textjoin(";",false,<YOUR_SPILL_RANGE>)`